# Wordpress jquery select a submenu item?

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I am trying to force a submenu item to be a certain color whenever I am on a certain page template, but I'm having a hard time getting the selector right + where to put the code. Here's the WP output for that section of the page:

```
<div class="header-menu-container">
<ul id="menu-menu-header" class="menu">
<li id="menu-item-2562" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-2562">
<li id="menu-item-2699" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-2699">
<li id="menu-item-2701" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-2701">
<li id="menu-item-2700" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-2700">
<li id="menu-item-2588" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent current_page_parent current_page_ancestor menu-item-2588">
<a href="http://www.luckymedia.com/clients/Linus/content/?page_id=2585">Services</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
<li id="menu-item-3344" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-3344">
<li id="menu-item-3345" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-3322 current_page_item menu-item-3345">
<li id="menu-item-3459" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3459">
<li id="menu-item-3462" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3462">
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: do you want to highlight the current page, or change the color of the links for different page templates?

Comment: I want to change the color of the second sub-menu item only in a specific page template.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
.current_page_item{
    color:red; /* any color here */
}
```

Comment: I want to change the color of the second sub-menu item only in a specific page template.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need jquery, it is pure css. try:

```
.current_page_item .sub-menu li{
       color:#aaa;
}
```

or maybe just:

```
.sub-menu li{
       color:#aaa;
}
```